# Android: cordova splash animation

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

Hi I'm using cordova::splash

Is there any way to implement an animation on splash screen? Anything like fade in/fade out or slide will do.

For a certain view, we can use an animation xml to implement dynamic effects, like this

```
    cordova_webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            cordova_webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
            cordova_webview.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in));
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="2200"></alpha>
    </set>
```

But for splash screen, I don't know if there is an actuall "view" for it.

Comment: i dont know what cordova is.. but if you need to knwo how to animate a normal splash screen i can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found but have not implemented yet. Hope it helps.
PhoneGap / Cordova Splash Screen Fix:
https://gist.github.com/tqc/2421350